# Is there a way to program an mouseover image that controls 2 divs [larger image AND a text description]

Tags: jquery, image, content-management-system, gallery, rollover

the design calls for an image gallery with thumbnails for different characters and when u roll over a thumbnail a larger version of the image appears and in a div to the left with a header and description for each character also appears.

1) is there a way to have a rollover control both divs? (enlarged image and description)

and

2) how would i need to go about syncing this up with a cms?

thank you for reading :)

Comment: thanks for the help so far you guys! VERY insightful.

for CMS's im kind of open to suggestions. id kind of prefer wordpress if possible but only because ive worked with it before.

thanks again!

Comment: So did you get your answer? Please check the appropriate one and up vote it if you would :)

Comment: they all helped in their own ways. i think the pstanton's way will be the one i build from though. makes the most sense to me, but i may be wrong.

thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a start, not sure what cms you're using etc so nfi how to answer that part:

HTML:

```
<a class="info" href="" onclick="return false;">
  <img src="thumb.jpg"/>
  <span><img src="large.jpg" /><br />
   description goes here</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.info              {z-index:24; position:relative; color:#999; font-size:11px; text-transform:none; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #999; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; margin:5px;}
a.info:hover        {z-index:25; text-decoration:none; color:#333; border-color:#333;}
a.info span         {display:none; position:absolute; top:15px; left:15px; width:240px; color:#000; font-size:12px; background-color:#fff; padding:2px; border:1px solid #333;}
a.info:hover span   {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, store information about the character in the id tag of the trigger element.  Like say it is mickey mouse, id="mickey" maybe you are using prototype...

```
$$('.trigger').each(function (el) {el.observe('mouseover',showInfo.bind(el);});
```

Then the function showInfo shows the divs that have the larger image and info

```
function showInfo(ev) {
    // this refers to the element that has the mouse over, which has the descriptive id
    var infoContainerId = this.id+"_info";
    var imageContainerId = this.id+"_image";
    $(infoContainerId).show(); // showing the div id="mickey_info"
    $(imageContainerId).show(); // showing the div id="mickey_image"
}
```

Well.. just an example...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, this is untested but it would be something like this:

```
$('#myImageThumbnail').mouseenter(function(){

    //Set the description text
    $('#descriptionDiv').html('Insert character description here');

    //Enlarge the image
    $('#myImageThumbnail').attr('height','300');
    $('#myImageThumbnail').attr('width','200');
});

$('#myImageThumbnail').mouseleave(function(){

    //Remove the description text
    $('#descriptionDiv').html('');

    //Return image/thumbnail to original size
    $('#myImageThumbnail').attr('height','150');
    $('#myImageThumbnail').attr('width','100');
});
```

If you needed to pull dynamic info from a database for the description, simply look at the jQuery $.ajax function and set the description HTML to the returned value.